# Pseudorandom number generators in Haskell

Tags: haskell, random

I'm working on solutions to the latest Programming Praxis puzzles—[the first](http://programmingpraxis.com/2014/01/14/minimum-standard-random-number-generator/) on implementing the minimal standard random number generator and [the second](http://programmingpraxis.com/2014/01/17/shuffle-box/) on implementing a shuffle box to go with either that one or a different pseudorandom number generator. Implementing the math is pretty straightforward. The tricky bit for me is figuring out how to put the pieces together properly.

Conceptually, a pseudorandom number generator is a function `stepRandom :: s -> (s, a)` where `s` is the type of the internal state of the generator and `a` is the type of randomly chosen object produced. For a linear congruential PRNG, we could have `s = a = Int64`, for example, or perhaps `s = Int64` and `a = Double`. [This post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/202908/how-do-functional-languages-handle-random-numbers) on PSE does a pretty good job of showing how to use a monad to thread the PRNG state through a random computation, and finish things off with `runRandom` to run a computation with a certain initial state (seed).

Conceptually, a shuffle box is a function `shuffle :: box -> a -> (box, a)` along with a function to initialize a new box of the desired size with values from a PRNG. In practice, however, the representation of this box is a bit trickier. For efficiency, it should be represented as a mutable array, which forces it into `ST` or `IO`. Something vaguely like this:

```
mkShuffle :: (Integral i, Ix i, MArray a e m) => i -> m e -> m (a i e)
mkShuffle size getRandom = do
  thelist <- replicateM (fromInteger.fromIntegral $ size) getRandom
  newListArray (0,size-1) thelist

shuffle :: (Integral b, Ix b, MArray a b m) => a b b -> b -> m b
shuffle box n = do
  (start,end) <- getBounds box
  let index = start + n `quot` (end-start+1)
  value <- readArray box index
  writeArray box index n
  return value
```

What I really want to do, however, is *attach* an (initialized?) shuffle box to a PRNG, so as to "pipe" the output from the PRNG into the shuffle box. I don't understand how to set up that plumbing properly.

Comment: Are you sure you really need the efficiency provided by a mutable array? An unboxed but immutable array would probably be sufficient.

Comment: @icktoofay, I'm sure that would be fine for a smallish box, or for a box that the compiler can figure out is used in a single-threaded fashion, but at this point I'm more interested in the concept than I am in the application.

Comment: Which concept? Mutable arrays or "piping"? Each one can be demonstrated individually quite easily, but together they can be complex. If the goal is to modify the output of a PRNG with a shuffle box then I wrote a few lines that do that atop `mwc-random` and `vector`'s mutable Vectors, but that machinery is quite a bit more complex than what you have here.

Comment: @J.Abrahamson, the piping, and particularly how to put that together with the mutable arrays. Unfortunately, I may not really be ready for this yet, I suppose :/. Things in Haskell tend to go "Sure, I understand. OK, no problem. Of course. Easy. WAIT! WTF? What does that even mean????"

Comment: I'll go ahead and post a response then using `vector`, `mwc-random` and `pipes`. I believe it does what you want and, if you handwave around some of the highly generic types, it's not *too* hard to read.

Comment: You can use the ST monad and have it produce a lazy list.  That way you can hide ST.

Comment: @augustss, using the lazy version of ST, I assume? That would be a very different framework, but it's nice and simple. The only downside is that switching from a PRNG to a real RNG requires lazy IO, but still, it's certainly a clean approach.

Comment: If you want a real RNG you can use lazy IO to initialize the generator with an infinite stream on random bits.  Using the lazy list of random numbers would be the same in both cases, just with different ways of creating it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming that the goal is to implement an algorithm as follows: we have a random generator of some sort which we can think of as somehow producing a stream of random values

```
import Pipes

prng :: Monad m => Producer Int m r  

-- produces Ints using the effects of m never stops, thus the 
-- return type r is polymorphic
```

We would like to modify this PRNG via a shuffle box. Shuffle boxes have a mutable state `Box` which is an array of random integers and they modify a stream of random integers in a particular way

```
shuffle :: Monad m => Box -> Pipe Int Int m r   

-- given a box, convert a stream of integers into a different 
-- stream of integers using the effects of m without stopping 
-- (polymorphic r)
```

`shuffle` works on an integer-by-integer basis by indexing into its `Box` by the incoming random value modulo the size of the box, storing the incoming value there, and emitting the value which was previously stored there. In some sense it's like a stochastic delay function.

---

So with that spec let's get to a real implementation. We want to use a mutable array so we'll use the `vector` library and the `ST` monad. `ST` requires that we pass around a phantom `s` parameter that matches throughout a particular `ST` monad invocation, so when we write `Box` it'll need to expose that parameter.

```
import qualified Data.Vector.Mutable as Vm
import           Control.Monad.ST

data Box s = Box { sz :: Int, vc :: Vm.STVector s Int }
```

The `sz` parameter is the size of the `Box`'s memory and the `Vm.STVector s` is a mutable `ST` `Vector` linked to the `s` `ST` thread. We can immediately use this to build our shuffle algorithm, now knowing that the `Monad` `m` must actually be `ST s`.

```
import           Control.Monad

shuffle :: Box s -> Pipe Int Int (ST s) r
shuffle box = forever $ do                          -- this pipe runs forever
  up <- await                                       -- wait for upstream
  next <- lift $ do let index = up `rem` sz box     -- perform the shuffle
                    prior <- Vm.read (vc box) index --   using our mutation
                    Vm.write (vc box) index up      --   primitives in the ST
                    return prior                    --   monad
  yield next                                        -- then yield the result
```

---

Now we'd just like to be able to attach this `shuffle` to some `prng` `Producer`. Since we're using `vector` it's nice to use the high-performance `mwc-random` library.

```
import qualified System.Random.MWC   as MWC

-- | Produce a uniformly distributed positive integer
uniformPos :: MWC.GenST s -> ST s Int
uniformPos gen = liftM abs (MWC.uniform gen)

prng :: MWC.GenST s -> Int -> ST s (Box s)
prng gen = forever $ do 
  val <- lift (uniformPos gen)
  yield val
```

Notice that since we're passing the PRNG seed, `MWC.GenST s`, along in an `ST s` thread we don't need to catch modifications and thread them along as well. Instead, `mwc-random` uses a mutable `STRef s` behind the scenes. Also notice that we modify `MWC.uniform` to return positive indices only as this is required for our indexing scheme in `shuffle`.

We can also use `mwc-random` to generate our initial box.

```
mkBox :: MWC.GenST s -> Int -> ST s (Box s)
mkBox gen size = do 
  vec <- Vm.replicateM size (uniformPos gen)
  return (Box size vec)
```

The only trick here is the very nice `Vm.replicateM` function which effectively has the constrained type

```
Vm.replicateM :: Int -> ST s Int -> Vm.STVector s Int
```

where the second argument is an `ST s` action which generates a new element of the vector.

---

Finally we have all the pieces. We just need to assemble them. Fortunately, the modularity we get from using `pipes` makes this trivial.

```
import qualified Pipes.Prelude       as P

run10 :: MWC.GenST s -> ST s [Int]
run10 gen = do
  box <- mkBox gen 1000
  P.toListM (prng gen >-> shuffle box >-> P.take 10)
```

Here we use `(>->)` to build a production pipeline and `P.toListM` to run that pipeline and produce a list. Finally we just need to execute this `ST s` thread in `IO` which is also where we can create our initial `MWC.GenST s` seed and feed it to `run10` using `MWC.withSystemRandom` which generates the initial seed from, as it says, `SystemRandom`.

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  result <- MWC.withSystemRandom run10
  print result
```

And we have our pipeline.

```
*ShuffleBox> main
[743244324568658487,8970293000346490947,7840610233495392020,6500616573179099831,1849346693432591466,4270856297964802595,3520304355004706754,7475836204488259316,1099932102382049619,7752192194581108062]
```

---

Note that the actual operations of these pieces is not terrifically complex. Unfortunately, the types in `ST`, `mwc-random`, `vector`, and `pipes` are all each individually *highly* generalized and thus can be quite burdensome to comprehend at first. Hopefully the above, where I've deliberately weakened and specialized nearly every type to this exact problem, will be much easier to follow and provide a little bit of intuition for how each of these wonderful libraries works individually and together.

Comment: It will take me at least a day or two to digest this. If I understand it by the end, I will be very happy to accept this answer.

Comment: Note that using a high-quality PRNG really isn't the point at all. The point is to be able to plug in whatever PRNG I want. One thing concerns me a bit: conceptually, a PRNG with a shuffle box attached to it is *itself* a PRNG. It's not yet clear to me whether your code reflects this. That may just be because I don't understand half of it yet.

Comment: The use of `mwc-random` was more because once we're in the realm of mutability and ST it's quite natural to use `vector` and `mwc-random` as canonical.

Comment: This implementation does reflect that `prng` and `prng + shuffle` are both the same type. Explicitly, we can see that `prng gen` and `prng gen >-> shuffle box` both have type `Producer Int (ST s) r` which reads as "produce of integers atop the ST monad".

Comment: You could thus, if you like, keep going: `prng gen >-> shuffle box1 >-> shuffle box2 >-> shuffle box3`.

Comment: It's also worth noting that the entire example can be switched to `IO` instead of `ST` by changing `Box` and some of the type annotations. That's why `mwc-random` and `vector` have complex types—they're generic over `IO` and `ST`.

Comment: I'm way too tired to even try right now, but I will read it carefully when I am alert. I greatly appreciate your assistance regardless.

Comment: Feel free to email me if you have further questions about this example.